# Error: Can only supply single unnamed argument to do()

Tags: r, visualization, large-data

I tried to use the code from following link for a large data set visualization using bigvis package

http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7457_8740a6a481f042ad8d2bce17e7b5bd04.html#Grouped

The function from the link is:

```
bin_by <- function(.data, ...){
 plyr:::list_to_dataframe(do(.data,
                          function(.data, ...){
                            eval(substitute(condense(bin(...))),
                                 env=.data,
                                 enclos=parent.frame())
                          }
                          , ...)
 ,labels=attr(.data, 'labels'))
}
```

but when I ran it R gave me such error:

Error: Can only supply single unnamed argument to do()
  Called from: named_args(args)

Can anyone help me to understand this? Thank you so much!!
I don't want to directly run condense and bin because I wanna do boxplot, which I would also really appreciate it if anyone can tell me how to do it with bigvis.

Comment: Given its date, I think that tutorial was based a very early version of dplyr. At this point, `dplyr::do` adds a list column if its parameters are named. If they're not, it expects them to return a single data.frame (which could only be a single parameter). I can't wholly predict what it used to do when passed data and a function...maybe something similar to `do.call`/`purrr::invoke`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function dplyr::do and bugvis::bin have been changed greatly. The following code will work (update bigvis/dplyr to the current 2017-04-28 Github version)

Indeed, you no longer need list_to_dataframe anymore. I think the `do` function will not accept more than one unnamed arguments. Additionally, since '...' is used to pass unquoted symbols, it is always a good habit to check whether the function (here is the bigvis::vis) has been updated.

Note:

1. `dplyr::do` function could be deleted here
2. `plyr::list_to_dataframe` causes other problems as the return value of do/bin functions have been updated.

```html
library(ggplot2)
library(bigvis)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

f<-function(.data,x, width){
  eval(substitute(condense(bin(x, width=width))),
       env=.data,
       enclos=parent.frame())
}

bin_by <- function(.data, x, width){
  do(.data,f(.,x,width = width))
}

num <- 10e6
binwidth=1
obs <- rbind(data.frame(x=rnorm(num), name='normal'),
             data.frame(x=rnorm(num, sd=6), name='wide'),
             data.frame(x=rnorm(num, mean=3), name='right'))

bins <- bin_by(obs, x, binwidth)
ggplot(data=bins, aes(x=x, y=.count)) + geom_line() + geom_area(alpha=1/10, position="identity")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It worked perfectly